# warning about incompatible pointer type - c

Tags: c, pointers, char, strtok

I call my function from my main as so...

```
int main() {

   char* input[81];
   char** array[81];

   userInput(input);

   parseInput(input);

}
```

userInput is taking in input and storing in the input variable. this is working correctly.

but now I want to send both the input and a char pointer array to my parseInput function to parse the input into an array using strtok

the following is my parseInput() function...

```
void parseInput(char* in) {

   char *tok = strtok(in, " ");

   int i = 0;
   while(tok != NULL) {

      array[i] = tok;
      tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
      i++;

   }

}
```

when I try to compile I am getting the following warning and I do not understand why.

warning: passing argument 1 of ‘userInput’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
userInput(input);

warning: passing argument 1 of ‘parseInput’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
parseInput(input, array);

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. thank you

Comment: 1 pointer to char, is different to 81 pointers to char .  To help us understand what you are trying to do, it would help to show the `userInput` function.  Also, the `parseInput` function should fail to compile due to `array` not being visible

Answer (score 2):

You defined the function `parseInput` as taking a parameter of type `char*`, but in the function `main`, you are passing it a [decayed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) parameter of type `char**`. That is why your compiler is complaining about an incompatible pointer type.

Instead of

`char* input[81];`

you should probably write:

`char input[81];`

Also, the declaration

`char** array[81];`

should probably be changed to:

`char* array[81];`

Also, as already pointed out in the comments section, the function `parseInput` will not compile, because it refers to an identifier `array`, but no identifier with that name is visible to that function. It cannot see the identifier `array` of the function `main`. Therefore, if you want the function `parseInput` to have access to `array` in the function `main`, then, when calling `parseInput`, you must pass a pointer to that array.

An additional problem with your code is that the behavior of the function `parseInput` does not make sense, as the caller of that function (in this case `main`) has no way of knowing how many elements of the pointer array were written by `parseInput`. Therefore, it has no way of knowing how many elements of the array are valid after the function call. For this reason, it would probably make more sense to make the function `parseInput` return an `int` which specifies the number of array elements written.

Another problem is that the function `parseInput` simply assumes that the passed array is large enough. If that assumption is false, then it will cause a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Therefore, it would probably be safer to design the function `parseInput` in such a way that it is also passed an argument which specifies the size of the passed array, so that the function can stop before a buffer overflow occurs.

After applying all of the modifications mentioned above, the function `parseInput` would look like this:

```
int parseInput( char* in, char** results, int results_length )
{
    char *tok = strtok(in, " ");

    int i = 0;
    while( tok != NULL && i < results_length )
    {
        results[i] = tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Instead of calling the function like this

```
parseInput(input);
```

you would now call it like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char input[81] = "This is a test.";
    char* array[81];
    int num_elements;

    num_elements = parseInput( input, array, sizeof array / sizeof *array );

    for ( int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", array[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This test program provides the following output:

```
This
is
a
test.
```